# How to add a given number of rows and columns to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science

I have an numpy array of shape (2000,1) and I need the shape to be (2000,7).
The values in the 6 column we are adding can be anything.
Is there a function or method to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `numpy.hstack` for this.

```py
>>> x = np.zeros((2000, 1))
>>> x.shape
(2000, 1)
>>> x = np.hstack((x, np.zeros((2000, 6))))
>>> x.shape
(2000, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting option is *np.pad* function.

The second parameter (*pad_with* - a list of 2-tuples) defines how many
elements to add at the beginning / end of each dimension.

Example:

```
arr = np.arange(1,7)[:, np.newaxis]
arr.shape         # (6, 1)
result = np.pad(arr, [(0, 0), (0, 6)])
result.shape      # (6, 7)
```

There can be passed also third parameter - *mode* - defining various
ways **what value** to pad with. For details see the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with broadcasting:

```
x = np.zeros((2000, 1))
np.broadcast_to(x, (2000,7))
```

In this case, the values in the first row will be repeated along the second axis.